# Matrix exponential of a skew-symmetric Toeplitz matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trigonometry, matrix-exponential

From today's exam:

> Given the following matrix,
> $$B = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -2/3 & 1/3\\ 2/3 & 0 & -2/3\\ -1/3 & 2/3 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$ Prove that $$\exp(aB) = I + \sin(a) B + (1 -\cos(a)) B^2$$

---

I have tried expanding the exponential
$$\exp(aB)=I+aB+\frac{a^2}{2}B^2+\frac{a^3}{3!}B^3 + \cdots$$

But could not manage to find the $B^k$ expression.
Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Try the following: Find some $b \in \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $B^2 = bb^\top - (b^\top b)I$. Then find a formula for $B^{2n+1}$ that solely depends on $b$ and $B^1$. Then you have to write: $\displaystyle \exp(aB) = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{a^{2k}}{(2k)!}B^{2k} + \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{a^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!} B^{2k+1}$. Also consider series representations of $\sin$ and $\cos$.

Comment: @cosmo5 Fixed. I don’t use latex that much. Thanks

Comment: @A.Othmane Ok. Can you also add your calculations of $B^2$ and $B^3$? I'm seeing a pattern.

Answer (score 4):

The characteristic polynomial of the given matrix is $x^3 +x$. Hence by Cayley-Hamilton theorem,
\begin{align*}
B^3+B&=0\\
B^3 &= -B\\
B^4 &= -B^2\\
B^5 &= B\\
\vdots\\
\exp(aB)&= I + aB+\frac{a^2B^2}{2!}+\frac{a^3B^3}{3!}+\cdots\\
\exp(aB) &= I + \left(a-\frac{a^3}{3!}+\cdots \right) B + \left( \frac{a^2}{2!}-\frac{a^4}{4!}+\cdots \right)B^2  &&\square\\
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks I got it.